# Add a column of time difference for each group

Tags: r, datetime

I have a data frame.

```
DeviceID       AreaID       Time
325            10152        04:40:36
325            10221        04:45:36
325            10152        12:45:12
525            10152        09:58:32
525            10221        10:03:39
...................................
```

I want to add a column of Time Difference based on the following condition:
I need the time difference for every DeviceID if the time of AreaID 10152 and 10221 are within 1 hour. Otherwise it will be NA.

The outcome should be like this:

```
DeviceID       AreaID       Time            TimeDifference
325            10152        04:40:36        00:05:00
525            10152        09:58:32        00:05:07
................................
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
# Load data sample
dat = read.table(text="DeviceID       AreaID       Time
325            10152        04:40:36
                 325            10221        04:45:36
                 325            10152        12:45:12
                 525            10152        09:58:32
                 525            10221        10:03:39", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(hms)
library(tidyverse)

dat$Time = as.hms(dat$Time)

dat %>% 
  group_by(DeviceID) %>% 
  mutate(TimeDifference = as.hms(lead(Time) - Time)) %>% 
  filter(TimeDifference <= 60*60)
```

> ```
>   DeviceID AreaID     Time TimeDifference
>      <int>  <int>   <time>         <time>
> 1      325  10152 04:40:36       00:05:00
> 2      525  10152 09:58:32       00:05:07
> ```